# Where did Bob Ross get his inspiration?

Tags: analysis, origin

After watching the Bob Ross movie and learning about how he spent much of his life in Vermont, USA, I wonder where his inspiration for his paintings came from? If his paintings were from this area, where would it resemble the best?

A compilation of some of his paintings:
[image: A compilation of his paintings]

See also this TikTok video:

https://www.tiktok.com/@bobrossdailyvids/video/7244965938213309722

Comment: Not especially relevant, but quite interesting; https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/a-statistical-analysis-of-the-work-of-bob-ross/

Comment: Not sure where his inspiration came from; however, I am 100% certain that all of his trees are happy :P

Comment: Love the way he painted all of his works that in the compilation you see as if he created an animation!

Comment: Why is the sky blue? Why is water wet?
Why did Judas rat to the Romans while Jesus slept?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

According to [this Fox News article](https://www.foxnews.com/entertainment/bob-ross-air-force-joy-of-painting), he was inspired by the nature of Alaska:

> His pal Joan Kowalski, president of Bob Ross Inc., told Fox News that it was during the star’s time in the Air Force that he fell in love with the Alaskan landscape, compelling him to paint.
>
> “First and foremost, he was stationed in Alaska and that landscape just moved him with the incredible mountains and snow caps,” she explained. “Those paintings that Bob [made], those are real, incredible scenes that you would see in Alaska. And that really affected him being stationed there.”

**Update** per OP's request to add the exact location:

From the book [*Happy Clouds, Happy Trees: The Bob Ross Phenomenon*](https://books.google.com/books?id=FT8kAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA13&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=2#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Kristin G. Congdon, Doug Blandy, Danny Coeyman:

> Ross, who joined the US Air Force in Florida at the age of eighteen, was not only a bartender, but a medical records technician at the **Eielson Air Force Base**, about twenty miles outside of Fairbanks.

Another location based on [this New York Times article](https://www.nytimes.com/1991/12/22/arts/television-bob-ross-the-frugal-gourmet-of-painting.html):

> he took his first painting class at the **Anchorage U.S.O. club**, became hooked, and spent years going from art class to art class.

Furthermore, one of Bob Ross' famous works is the painting of [Mount Denali](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denali) also known as Mount McKinley which is the highest peak in Alaska:

[Mt. McKinley painting on IMDB](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt2177153/)

Comment: Thank you for the edit @V2Blast . Unfortunately, I live in Iran and Fox News is blocked here. So I couldn't open the site, just saw its title in the Google Search.

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Comment: Alaska is pretty broad. Some exact locations would add tremendously to this answer.

Comment: @Justintimeforfun Updated the answer.